# Click event on html element behind clipped event SVG

Tags: svg, clip-path

I have clipped an svg image by rect, but now onclick on that clipped portion how to trigger an onclick event on the rect and not the image.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnuboz21/

```
<div class="feature">
<img src="http://en.hdyo.org/assets/art-shutter-young-people-a12e2c0cd7a54920cb024fd1394190fd.jpg">
<svg class="glass">
  <image id="svg-image" width="980" height="652" xlink:href="http://en.hdyo.org/assets/art-shutter-young-people-a12e2c0cd7a54920cb024fd1394190fd.jpg" clip-path="url(#svg-mask)" />
  <filter id="svg-blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" />
  </filter>

  <clipPath id="svg-mask">


    <rect x="325" y="110" rx="40" ry="40" width="150" height="150"  style="fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.7"/>
  </clipPath>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Stick an onclick handler on the `<image>` element.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you for your reply, but what I need is in case i have multiple rect inside the clip path to clip different portion of image, I need to bind onclick events on each of the rectangle.

I have updated the fiddle with multiple rects http://jsfiddle.net/dnuboz21/2/

Comment: You need a different approach then. Create individual rects and fill them with parts of images via patterns. Or create multiple transparent rects that match the clipPath pieces and handle click event on those.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, creating individual rects and filling them with image via patterns worked for me.